# AngularJs 2 Http CONNECTION ERROR

Tags: http, angular, get, webpack

AngularJs 2 with Webpack.
I am not able to connect to NYT Api.
**ALL ENDOPOINTS TESTED AND WORKING PROPERLY**
AngularJs 2 in production mode:

```
enableProdMode();
```

App:
-1 component
-1 Service

**All other components working/displaying properly.**
No other services on app yet.

**Service returns with error:** (in console)

```
error: "Collection 'topstories' not found"
```

[image: error-from-console]

**The Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams, Response } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class NewsService {

    private topStoriesUrl: string = `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/politics.json`;
//  private topStoriesUrl: string = `https://newsapi.org/v1/articles`;

        // Injecting Http capabilities
    constructor( private http: Http ) {}

        // for error handling
    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any>{
        console.error("FromSERVICE:::---:::-->   ", error);
        return Promise.reject( error.message || error );
    }

    getNews(): Observable<any> {

      let parms: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
      parms.set("api-key", "184db335652341518bea3e4a5db85494");
 //   parms.set("source", "associated-press");
 //   parms.set("apiKey", "e4e2aa62a883464a87547e8de4336f61");

      return this.http.get( this.topStoriesUrl, { search: parms } )
        .map( (res: Response) => res['articles'] )
        .catch( this.handleError );
   }
}
```

**The Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit }    from '@angular/core';
import { Router }                       from '@angular/router';
import { Observable }                   from 'rxjs';

  // service for fetcing news from api
import { NewsService } from '../services/news.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'main-news',
  templateUrl: '../templates/main-news.component.html'
})

export class MainNewsComponent implements OnInit{

    private news: Observable<any>;

    constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private newsService: NewsService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
      this.newsService.getNews().subscribe( {
          next: r => this.news = Observable.of<any[]>(["one"]),
          error: err => console.error("From COMPONENT--->", err)
    } );
  }
}
```

I have tried this call with both Api from different organizations to get
the same error on the URL resource.
**I have tried this same call with said URL with a Ruby script (NET/http) and also directly on the browser address bar, to receive a VALID response on these BOTH cases.**
NOT SURE WHY IT FAILS WITH ANGULAR.
HELP!!!

Comment: What version are you using of http? I recently had API issues with 2.1.1/2.1.2 and went back to 2.0.0.

Comment: Just tried with Angular 2.0   
and getting same issue  
Starting on Plunker to see if it persists and narrow it down to either: 1. my system; or 2. AngularJs 2 config.
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Turns out I was missing the:**

```
Access-control-allow-origin
```

header.
Go figure!
Apparently, it is not added automatically by AngularJs 2.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

From your console error it looks like the url is not found on server.
The error displayed is returned from server its not angularjs specific error.
Notice 404 not found returned.
So check your url and server again.

Comment: Already tested all end points. It was a simple header issue. see answer above. thnx.